# If Gaussian random vector has singular covariance matrix, isn't there probability density function?

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, covariance, singularity-theory

I got a complicated problem.
Suppose that Gaussian random vector having Covariance matrix;
$$K_X=\left[\begin{matrix}1 &-\frac12 &-\frac12 \\ -\frac12 &1 &-\frac12 \\ -\frac12 &-\frac12 &1\end{matrix}\right]$$
It is clearly singular since $\mathrm{det}|K_X|=0.$
However problem maker told me that find out that Gaussian pdf but I know that Jointly Gaussian pdf equation includes the inverse matrix of $K_X$ but in our case, there is no inverse matrix since $K_X$ is singular.
Do I really find out pdf nothing?
Let me ask you question.
Thank you.

Comment: Related: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/77973/normal-distribution-with-positive-semi-definite-covariance-matrix

Comment: I don't think the determinant of this matrix is 0. In fact it can't be because the rows are linearly independent.

Comment: @MattS Sure they are dependent. If $k_i$ is the $i$th row, then $k_1=-k_2-k_3$.